# Firebase : Send count reduced since Feb. Notification_Open event showing name as 'not-set' for most of the events

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

My iOS app is using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications.

Since Feb 2021, the send count for the notifications have reduced by more than 60%. We see a major drop in the number of sends.

Also, we have seen a drop in the notification_open event count on the Firebase dashboard. Most of the events are displayed as name = not-set in the console.

Any insights on the above behaviour is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase team suggested that have an issue on their end and are working to fix the issue of notifications not being tagged.

ETA for the change was not provided.